# Is it acceptable practice to change the behavior of old HTML tags?

Tags: html, javascript, tags

In my app I need to display some maps. So I use `Leaflet.js` to do so, but to simplify my HTML I have used a `<map>` tag to do so. Is that acceptable, or should I avoid doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by using `map` to display some maps and by changing the behavior of old tags? The `map` element does not display anything (it only defines areas in an image).

Comment: `map` is not an old element and is part of HTML5.

Comment: I don't found any info that `map` is deprecated. I mean that in my JS I'm looking for all `<map>` tags, in them I create `<div>` with unique, generated `id` and in them I display my Leaflet map.

Answer (score 3):

From accessibility this would be incorrect, because `<map>` tag is:

> The map element, in conjunction with any area element descendants, defines an image map.

([source from W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map))

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags) gives a good answer about custom elements.

Comment: No. Do not create your own HTML tags. Use XHTML if you want to do that. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your comment , you are right! Edited the answer!